# Asterisk Фоновая музыка через ChanSpy()

Tags: asterisk

Есть небольшой контекст, где внутри EAGI скрипта слушаются реплики абонента и с помощью Playback() проигрываются аудиофайлы.

extensions.conf

```
[test]
exten => 1,1,Set(fname=${UNIQUEID})
exten => 1,n,MixMonitor(/records/${fname}.wav)
exten => 1,n,EAGI(<path_to_script>)
```

Задача наложить фоновый шум во время всего разговора. Прочитал, что можно сделать это через ChanSpy(). Соответственно дописал в диалплан следующее:

```
[test]
exten => 1,1,originate(Local/1@noise,app,playback,<path_to_audio>)
exten => 1,n,Set(fname=${UNIQUEID})
exten => 1,n,MixMonitor(/records/${fname}.wav)
exten => 1,n,EAGI(<path_to_script>)

[noise]
exten => 1,1,Answer()
exten => 1,n,ChanSpy(SIP/<channel>, qsW)
```

В итоге фоновый шум слышен только тогда, когда в скрипте выполняется Playback(), то есть во время трансляции аудио. Во время ожидания ответа абонента тишина. Можно ли транслировать фоновый шум во время всей беседы с помощью ChanSpy()? Нашел еще метод с созданием конференции, но к нему прибегать не очень хотелось бы.

Answer (score 0):

> метод с созданием конференции, но к нему прибегать не очень хотелось бы

Так либо так или через правку исходников asterisk`а, чтобы скрипт мог выдавать аудио в asterisk, а в скрипте заниматься микшированием двух аудио файлов (шум + реплики).

P.S. Бота что ли делаете ?